# Checking detailed parameters of hardware - like RAM CAS latency

Tags: software-recommendation, memory, cpu, system-information

In Windows one can find free apps like CPUID (CPU-Z) and others who help get a lot of information about installed hardware. I was looking for something similar for macOS, but couldn't find anything suitable or giving such a wide range of information. Of course there is System Information app, but it's not very detailed.

Is there a program (command line tool/paid graphical application) which could give me a similar extent of information to CPU-Z?

For example: CAS latency and timings for RAM modules, list of supported instruction sets for the CPU, details on the discrete GPU card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MacCPUID](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/download-maccpuid.html) can list instruction set support (as well as other details about the CPU). You can see various GPU details in System Profiler, under "Graphics/Displays", I'm not sure what information you're looking for exactly. As for RAM latency, you can open up the computer and check the label on the RAM stick. I'm not sure why you'd need that info, it's not like you'll be doing overclocking on a Mac.